# Not able to send UTF-8 email using delphi indy

Tags: delphi, unicode, indy

Here is my code

Email body has got some unicode characters

```
  LSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  try
    LMsg := TIdMessage.Create(LSMTP);
    try
      with LMsg do
      begin
        Subject := Subj;
        Recipients.EMailAddresses := Email;    
        WriteToLog(cInformation,'To: '+Recipients.EMailAddresses);    
        From.Address := ReplaceVariables(From_Address);    
        From.Name    := ReplaceVariables(From_Name);    
        Body.Text    := EmailMessage;    
        ContentTransferEncoding := '8bit';    
        CharSet := 'UTF-8';    
        ContentType := 'text/plain';    
     end;
```

And this is what I get

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii <<<<< WRONG
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Date: Fri, 23 Mar 2012 17:53:19 +0000
```

Using delphi 2009

Answer (score 16):

That is by design.  When the `ContentType` property is being set, the property setter may update the `CharSet` property with a default value if the input does not explicitally specify a charset.  Certain content types, especially in the `text/` realm, have specific charset defaults dictated in various RFCs.  Indy tries to follow those rules as best it can.  As such, you need to set the `CharSet` property to your intended value *after* you have set the `ContentType` property, as you already discovered:

```
//LMsg.CharSet := 'UTF-8';
LMsg.ContentType := 'text/plain';
LMsg.CharSet := 'UTF-8';
```

You can also do this instead:

```
LMsg.ContentType := 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8';
```

**UPDATE**: as of July 23 2019, `ContentType` property setters now preserve the corresponding `CharSet` property value if it is already set and a charset is not specified in the new `ContentType` value.  So, the order in which paired `ContentType`+`CharSet` properties are set is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Got it working. Order of events is very important.

This one works:

```
LMsg.ContentType:='text/plain';
LMsg.CharSet:='UTF-8';
```

This one does not:

```
LMsg.CharSet:='UTF-8';
LMsg.ContentType:='text/plain';
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, If i add an attachement, i must only specify the charset :

`pMsg->CharSet = "UTF-8";`

Else the mailreader show the source code of the mail.